# How to merge a double arraylist with a string arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, file-io, merge

## Context

I have an assignment that is asking me to read a recipe from a text file and manipulate the contents like units of measurement and ingredient quantity's. I separated the parts of the recipe into an arraylist to manipulate the ingredients, for the user will input whether they want to use imperial or metric units. From here I have created a double arraylist for separated quantity's from the original list, so 4 tbsp of salt just become 4.0. After this the user can enter if they want to change the recipe's serving size, so 4.0 can become any positive number like 8.0. I have coded all of this up until the point where I need to merge the manipulated array lists back together to output to the user. So the original string arraylist of 4 serving sizes:

```
[2 tbsp olive oil, 3 tbsp garlic, minced, 2 tsp dried parsley, 1 cup eggplant, cut into half inch cubes, 0.5 tbsp salt, 1 cup Parmesan cheese]
```

has to be combined with the corresponding double arraylist of the new 8 serving sizes:

```
[4.0, 6.0, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0]
```

to get:

```
[4 tbsp olive oil, 6 tbsp garlic, minced, 4 tsp dried parsley, 2 cup eggplant, cut into half inch cubes, 1 tbsp salt, 2 cup Parmesan cheese]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## Code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class Main {

    /**
     * Prints methods to user
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        printer1();
        servingReader();
        System.out.println(sSize);
        ingrReader();
        System.out.println(ingrList);
        ingrSeperator();
        System.out.println(SeperatorImperialList);
        choice();
    }//end main

    /**
     * Prints origanal recipe to user
     */
    public static void printer1() throws Exception{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("/home/runner/recipe.txt"));
        //original text file printed to the user before manipulation
        while (sc.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
        }
        sc.close();//scanner closed
    }

    static int sSize;//int for serving size

    /**
     * Reads text file
     */
    public static void servingReader() throws Exception{

        //recipe read
        File recipe = new File("/home/runner/recipe.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(recipe);

        //loop to find serving size
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            String s = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            if(s.equals("SERVING SIZE")){
                sSize = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }

        sc.close();//scanner closed
    }//servingReader

    static ArrayList<String> ingrList = new ArrayList<>();//ArrayList for ingredients created

    static String scan;

    /**
     * Reads recipe and adds ingredients section to list
     */
    public static void ingrReader() throws Exception{

        //recipe read
        File recipe = new File("/home/runner/recipe.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(recipe);

        //loop to find ingredients section or recipe
        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            String s = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            //if scanner finds header INGREDIENTS, section added to ingrList
            if(s.equals("INGREDIENTS")){
                while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                    int i = 0;
                    scan = sc.nextLine();
                    ingrList.add(i, scan);
                    i+= 1;
                    //if nothing is found, breaks
                    if(scan.equals("")){
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        sc.close();//scanner closed

        Collections.reverse(ingrList);//reverse method reverses order of elements in ingrList

        int ingr1 = ingrList.size() - 1;
        ingrList.remove(ingr1);


    }//ingrReader

    static ArrayList<Double> SeperatorImperialList = new ArrayList<Double>();//ArrayList for seperated ingredients created

    /**
     * Seperates ingredient quantitys from ingredints list and adds to seperated list
     */
    public static void ingrSeperator(){

        double ingr2 = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i <ingrList.size(); i++){
            String split [] = ingrList.get(i).split(" ");
            ingr2 =  Double.parseDouble(split[0]);
            String str = String.format("%1.2f", ingr2);
            ingr2 = Double.valueOf(str);
            SeperatorImperialList.add(ingr2);

        }

    }//end ingrSeperator

    static int unit;
    /**
     * Gets choice of imperial or metric
     */
    public static void choice() throws Exception{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Use imperial(1) or metric(2) units");
        System.out.print("Enter 1 or 2: ");//serving size enetered
        unit = sc.nextInt();

        if (unit == 1){
            divideImperial();
        }
        else{
            converter();
        }

        sc.close();//scanner closed

    }//end choice

    //for imperial
    /**
     * Gets serving size input from user and then adjusts seperated ingredinets accordingly for imperial
     */
    public static void divideImperial() throws Exception{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your Imperial serving size: ");//serving size enetered
        int servingSize = sc.nextInt();

        for(int i=0;i<SeperatorImperialList.size();i++){
            SeperatorImperialList.set(i,SeperatorImperialList.get(i)*servingSize);//origanal quantiys multiplyed by new serving size
        }

        for(int i=0;i<SeperatorImperialList.size();i++){
            SeperatorImperialList.set(i,SeperatorImperialList.get(i)/4);//multiplyed quantitys now divided by origanal serving size 4
        }
        mergImperial();

        sc.close();//scanner closed

    }//end divideImperial

    static ArrayList<String> convertedList = new ArrayList<>();//ArrayList for metric ingredients created

    static ArrayList<Double> SeperatedMetricList = new ArrayList<Double>();//ArrayList for seperated metric ingredients created



    /**
     * Converts imperial to metric
     */
    public static void converter() throws Exception{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        //convert tbsp to ml
        for(int i = 0; i < ingrList .size(); i++){
            //if ingrList contains tbsp replaced with ml
            if(ingrList.get(i).contains("tbsp")){
                convertedList.add(ingrList.get(i).replace("tbsp", "ml"));
                //for(int j=0;j<ingrSeperatorList.size();j++){
                //ingrSeperatorList.set(j,ingrSeperatorList.get(j)*15);
                //}
            }
        }

        //convert cup to ml
        for(int i = 0; i < ingrList .size(); i++){
            //if ingrList contains cup replaced with ml
            if(ingrList.get(i).contains("cup")){
                convertedList.add(ingrList.get(i).replace("cup", "ml"));

                // for(int j=0;j<ingrSeperatorList.size();j++){
                //   ingrSeperatorList.set(j,ingrSeperatorList.get(j)*250);

                // }
            }
        }

        //convert tsp to ml
        for(int i = 0; i < ingrList .size(); i++){
            //if ingrList contains tsp replaced with ml
            if(ingrList.get(i).contains("tsp")){
                convertedList.add(ingrList.get(i).replace("tsp", "ml"));
                //   for(int j=0;j<ingrSeperatorList.size();j++){
                //       ingrSeperatorList.set(j,ingrSeperatorList.get(j)*5);
                //   }
            }
        }
        SeperatorMetric();

        sc.close();//scanner closed
    }//end converter

     /**
     * Seperates metric list
     */
    public static void SeperatorMetric() throws Exception{

        double ingr2 = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i <convertedList.size(); i++){
            String split [] = convertedList.get(i).split(" ");
            ingr2 =  Double.parseDouble(split[0]);
            String str = String.format("%1.2f", ingr2);
            ingr2 = Double.valueOf(str);
            SeperatedMetricList.add(ingr2);
            divideMetric();
        }

    }//end SeperatorMetric

    /**
     * Gets serving size input from user and then adjusts seperated ingredinets accordingly for metric
     */
    public static void divideMetric() throws Exception{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your Metric serving size: ");//serving size enetered
        int servingSize = sc.nextInt();

        for(int i=0;i<SeperatedMetricList.size();i++){
            SeperatedMetricList.set(i,SeperatedMetricList.get(i)*servingSize);//origanal quantiys multiplyed by new serving size
        }

        for(int i=0;i<SeperatedMetricList.size();i++){
            SeperatedMetricList.set(i,SeperatedMetricList.get(i)/4);//multiplyed quantitys now divided by origanal serving size 4
        }
        mergMetric();
        sc.close();//scanner closed

    }//end divideImperial

    

    /**
     * Merges imperial lists together
     */
    public static void mergImperial(){
      System.out.print(SeperatorImperialList);
      System.out.println("Imperial");
            //here I would merge the ingredients list with the new serving size list
    }//end mergImperial

    /**
     * Merges metric lists together
     */
    public static void mergMetric(){
      System.out.print(SeperatedMetricList);
      System.out.println("Metric");
            //here I would merge the metric converted ingredients list with the new serving size list
    }//end mergMetric

}//end main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code to merge `List<Double>` to `List<String>`

```
public static List<String> merge() throws Exception{

List<String> newStringList = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i <convertedList.size(); i++){
            String split [] = convertedList.get(i).split(" ");
            split[0] = SeperatedMetricList.get(i).toString();
            String joinedString = String.join(" ", split);
            newStringList.add(joinedString);
        }
       return newStringList;
    }
```

As a side Note : Please follow naming convention when declaring methods and variable.
[Java naming Convetions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/)

Comment: Thank you for the help, don't think I could have done this part without the help. Looking back at my code I definitely see that it gets pretty disorganized and confusing, I'll read up on java naming conventions and becoming more efficient in using methods and variables. Hopefully my next project will be easier to use and read, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a separate arraylist and use a for loop to dump both of your values together, granted you index them appropriately.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String unit = "Units";

    int indexVariable = 0;

    ArrayList<Double> doubleArrayList = new ArrayList<Double>();
    doubleArrayList.add(0, 0.0);
    doubleArrayList.add(1, 1.0);
    doubleArrayList.add(2, 2.0);
    doubleArrayList.add(3, 3.0);
    doubleArrayList.add(4, 4.0);

    ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    stringArrayList.add(0, "Flour");
    stringArrayList.add(1, "Egg");
    stringArrayList.add(2, "butter");
    stringArrayList.add(3, "water");
    stringArrayList.add(4, "Pot");

    ArrayList<String> combinedArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(Double d : doubleArrayList) 
    {           
        combinedArrayList.add(indexVariable, "[" + indexVariable + "]: " + d + " " + unit + " of " + stringArrayList.get(indexVariable));

        System.out.println(combinedArrayList.get(indexVariable));
        indexVariable++;
    }
}
```

You could also use `doubleArrayList.indexOf(d)` to replace the indexVariable.

Answer (score 1):

First, create an inner ingredient class to hold the information you need to merge.

```
private static class Ingredient {
    final String name;
    final double quantity
    Ingredient(String name, double quantity) {
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

Then change the merge method (I used the metric one). [I assume convertedList is the list holding ingredients here, correct if wrong.]

```
public static void mergMetric() {
  System.out.print(SeperatedMetricList);
  System.out.println("Metric");
        //here I would merge the metric converted ingredients list with the new serving size list
    ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredients = new ArrayList<Ingredient>();
    int length = Math.Min(SeperatedMetricList.size(), convertedList.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        ingredients.add(new Ingredient(convertedList.get(i), SeperatedMetricList.get(i)));
    }
    // The list 'ingredients' should be done now, do whatever you want with it.
}//end mergMetric
```